# How do I set an executable's working directory via the command line, prior to executing it?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, .net-framework

If I run a program on the command line whose location is resolved through the *Path* environment variable, the program's working directory is generally set to its installation directory.

I would like to run such a program from a console window and set its working directory to the current or other explicit directory.  I was able to do this by temporarily copying the program to my working directory -- is there another way to accomplish this within the cmd.exe or powershell.exe environments?

The windows shell analogy to this task is to create a shortcut and set the "Start In" property accordingly.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To explicitly set the working directory, a PowerShell solution would be to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet with the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter.

```
Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe -WorkingDirectory c:\temp
```

Using the alias `start`, positional parameter, and partial parameter name this could be written as:

```
start notepad.exe -wo c:\temp
```

CMD also has a `START` command. For this, use the `/D` parameter to specify the working directory:

```
START /D c:\temp notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 10):

The below will work, make appropriate substitutions and save it with a `.cmd` extension.

```
@echo off 
C:
chdir C:\desired\directory
C:\full\path\of\command.exe
```

Put this batch file in a directory in your `%PATH%` and you should be able to invoke it from any `cmd.exe` instance.

Comment: Note that funkiness may occur if the working directory and executable aren't on the same partition/drive.

Comment: @LawrenceC, However this solution requires a temporary file. It's better if this could be achieved using no temporary files

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in powershell (Don't forget the leading Dot)

```
. "C:\Program Files\SomeFolder\someScript.cmd"
```